# How do you stop a suspended job from receiving GUI interaction?

Tags: process

If you suspend a process from the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> everything from that process is suspended including the UI.

But if you interact with the UI while it is suspended the interactions are still captured and played through as soon as you unsuspend the process with a `fg` or `bg` is there a way to stop it from capturing or playing back the captured interactions?

Comment: There's no way to do that without modifying the source code of the program.

Comment: @bain Feel free to put that as an answer and I'll mark it as so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that without modifying the program source. The problem is that X will buffer the events until after the program is resumed. You would need to handle the suspend (`SIGTSTP`) signal, record the current time according to the X11 server, then after resume read the events, and discard them based on the event time (`XEvent->XButtonEvent->Time`).

Comment: And there is no way to tell X not to buffer those events right? I'm thinking maybe option flags or something.

Comment: Not that I know of. There is an environment variable `_Xdebug` which can be set to 1 to make events synchronous but even then X will still buffer events. Proof: run `xev | grep ButtonPress`, ctrl-z, then click on xev window several times, then `fg` in terminal.